# Replacing a cooktop - old is electric and new is electric induction - Can i use the same wire and just change the breaker?

Tags: electrical

the old unit has these specs
POWER / RATINGS

Amp Rating at 208V  40

Amp Rating at 240V  40

KW Rating at 208V   6.7

KW Rating at 240V   8.8

and the new unit is an induction with these specs?

208 - 240 V - 60 Hz

440 Watts at 3.3 Amps

240V - 7.8kW at 32.5 Amps

208V - 7.1kW at 34.1 Amps

the current breaker is a Twin with 30Amps on each one.

Can i use the existing wire?
What breaker do i need if i need to change?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Ranges are weird.  What guidance do the instructions give on wire and breaker size?

Comment: Also the word "Twin" is reserved for [breakers I call double-stuffs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc), which can't power an oven. Though if you have a GE or Crouse Hinds panel, it may look like a twin. The technical term for your breaker is "2-pole", but it'll be double wide in most cases.

Comment: Can you post pictures of your breaker panel please? Also, do you know what size wire was run to the old cooktop? Perhaps you could post photos of the outlet box for the cooktop wiring, for that matter?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the inside of the outlet box for the cooktop please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see what the instructions say about breaker protection and circuit size. I'd say no you can't use same wire and just change the breaker and there a good chance the wiring wasn't appropriate for your old cooktop. You probably need a forty amp breaker and #8 AWG CU wire. Again, check the installation directions to determine the electrical needs. Also verify what size wire you have installed. Your existing 30 amp breaker more than likely has #10 AWG wire attached which is good for 30 amps.

Comment: Thanks for replying....

Comment: this is what the old spec sheets says: You must use a three-wire, single-phase
AC 208Y/120 Volt or 240/120 Volt, 60 Hertz
electrical system with separate ground. the new spec sheets doesnt have anything else than what i already posted....:-(   did find this, so your right 40amps.....Electrical Specifications
Volts 240/208 Volts
Amps 40 Amps

Comment: @JayR  Don't they have an installation guide in the instruction manual?  Just curious.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping out...
https://elica.com/sites/default/files/upload/piani-cottura/nikolatesla_lib0146647_2018_ul.pdf
This is installer guide...not much in there.
I’m trying to save some money..so wanted to know before I get a sparky in....I will pull the cable through the house to save cost...hence the questions...I did buy a #10 wire so will exchange for #8 as you suggested...
[install guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdvww.jpg)